# Is there any algebra calculation library for .NET?

Tags: c#, algebra

For example, If I give the it a circle and a square, it can tell me how much area they overlaps.

Comment: Far too generic, or you're not being clear enough about what you need.

Comment: Technically, overlapping areas is the domain of geometry.  Are you interested in intersections in particular?

Comment: What if the library were written in VB.NET? Would that be ok?

Comment: Anything that can easily run with c# would be good. I may do something interesting.

Comment: just something that can calculate "area" if I describe the graph to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [list of numerical libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_Languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET).

I like [Math.Net](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)

Answer (score 0):

use [GPC](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/) library.